# When loading an image in JavaScript fails, how can you retrieve the specific error or HTTP status codes?

Tags: javascript, image, http-status-codes, handle, onerror

I've tried this a few different ways, and while I have found several that will catch *if* an error has occurred when loading an image, I'm trying to figure out how to determine what, exactly, the error was.  It looks like `onerror` returns an Event object rather than an Error object:  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp

Here's a trivial example, stripping out the Promise wrapper and other code not relevant to this question:

JSfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/4b3n2gwp/1/

```
function load_image(url) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
        console.log(`Image loaded:  ${img.src}`);
    }
    img.onerror = (e) => {
        console.log(`Could not load image '${img.src}':  ${JSON.stringify(e, null, 4)}`);
    }
    img.src = url
}

load_image('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png');

load_image('i_do_not_exist.jpg');
```

It looks like the event that is returned does not contain any useful information:

```
"Image loaded:  https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"

"Could not load image 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/i_do_not_exist.jpg':  {
    \&quot;isTrusted\&quot;: true
```

In this case, since the image does not exist, the browser's console is also separately logging a GET HTTP 404 error; is there any way to get this programmatically?